# How can I pick values for a quadratic formula that are easily solvable?

Tags: quadratics

I am dynamically creating worksheets and I need to come up with some `a`, `b` and `c` values for a quadratic equation that will yield an integer `x`. How can I do this?

Comment: $\{a,b,c\}=\{1,0,-n^2\}$?  or $\{a,b,c\}=\{1,-2n,n^2\}$

Comment: In the second case `a` will always be `1`. Can I somehow make that not the same always?

Comment: You can just multiply through by a constant. $\{m,-2mn,mn^2\}$

Comment: First, pick $a$, $b$ and $x$. Now, $ax^2+bx+c=0$, so $c=-ax^2-bx$.

Comment: You could always expand the product
$$
(a_1x - b_1)(a_2x - b_2) = \\
(a_1a_2) x^2 - (a_1b_2 + b_1a_2)x + b_1b_2
$$
it suffices to select integers $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ (with $a_1,a_2$ non-zero).  The solutions are $x = b_1/a_1, x = b_2/a_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply choose roots $r_1$, $r_2$ and second degree coefficient $\alpha\neq 0$ as integers, then expand the expression
$$p(x) = \alpha (x-r_1)(x-r_2). $$

**Example.** Let $\alpha = 2$, $r_1 = -1$ and $r_2 = 3$, then we get

$$p(x) = 2(x-(-1))(x-3) = 2x^2 - 4x -6, $$
which has the requested integer roots $-1$ and $3$.

**Coefficients.** By expanding $p(x)$ in general you get that
$$p(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$$
with
\begin{align}
A &= \alpha\\
B &= -\alpha(r_1 + r_2)\\
C &= \alpha r_1 r_2.
\end{align}